# Factorization of a number obtained by a modular multiplication operation can reveal factors of the used operands?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider a number $r$ obtained by:

$r=a⋅b \mod n$

Knowning the factorization of $r$ can reveal some information (bits) of $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: prime factorization?

Comment: @user3491648 yes

Comment: I think no. If $n$ is prime then there is a $b$ for any $a \not= 0$, and given an $a$ it's easy to find $b$.

Comment: For $n$ non-prime, you can decide if $b$ exists given $a$ and compute its inverse. This is by using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: the factorization is neither $a$ or $b$

Answer (score 0):

If $r \neq 0$ and $n$ a prime number, by fixing $a = 1,...,n-1$ and then $b = a^{-1} r \mod{n}$ you have found $n-1$ solutions for $r$. Thus the factorization of $r$ can not reveal information about $a$ and $b$ since there is not a unique solution to your equation. It is the same for the system of equations:
$$ \begin{cases} 
r_1 = a b_1 \mod{n}\\
r_2 = a b_2 \mod{n}\\
...\\
r_m = a b_m \mod{n}
\end{cases}$$
You can set $a = 1,...,n-1$ and $b_1 = a^{-1} r_1 \mod{n}$, ..., $b_m = a^{-1} r_m \mod{n}$. And again you do not have a unique solution.